# Display a list of metafield files using shopify liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

sadly I'm not able to get this simple piece of code running:

```
{% for field in product.metafields.custom.anleitung %}
{{ field | first }}: {{ field | last }}
{% endfor %}
```

I have three files in a file - list metafield and simply want them to get displayed on my site. (number of files varies)

Comment: Why are you using `first`and `last`filters?

Comment: Idk, I just want to show all files contained in the metafield and found this solution online.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% for field in product.metafields.custom.anleitung.value %}
  <div><a href="{{ field.url }}">Anleitung downloaden</a></div>
{% endfor %}
```

See [Accessing metafields of type list](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#metafield-accessing-metafields-of-type-list) for the syntax to loop over list values.

Instead of `field.url`, you can use [`metafield_text`](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters#metafield_text) filter: `<a href="{{ field | metafield_text }}">Anleitung downloaden</a>`.

Or, you can use [`metafield_tag`](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters#metafield_tag-file_reference) and rely on Shopify to generate the link: `{{ field | metafield_tag }}`

Comment: Thank you very much! Sadly I'm still unable to get to the files. I tried this, but it hasn't worked yet:

{% for field in product.metafields.custom.anleitung.value %}
<div><a href="{{ product.metafields.custom.anleitung.value }}">Anleitung 
downloaden</a></div>
{% endfor %}

Comment: @SebastianMühlbauer See the edit please.

Comment: Thank you so much for your edit. It is indeed exactly what I've searched for. Sadly it still isn't working. I used: {% for field in product.metafields.custom.anleitung.value %}
{{ field | metafield_tag }}
{% endfor %}
but I only get a: Liquid error (line 2): metafield_tag can only be used with a metafield drop Liquid error. I have a metafield with 3 pdfs.

Comment: What about the first one: `<a href="{{ field.url }}">Anleitung downloaden</a>`? Do you get any error messages for it?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having trouble getting this to work with multiple pdfs/files, I have a working solution:

```
<p>Datasheet technical information for this product.</p>

{% assign file = product.metafields.custom.technical_datasheet.value %}

{% for field in file %}
{% assign file_output = file %}
 {% assign file_url = field.url %}
  {% assign file_name_with_shopify_extension = file_url | split: '/' | last %} <!-- parse the file name from the URL -->
  {% assign file_name = file_name_with_shopify_extension | split: '?' | first %} <!-- strip off the ?v=123456789 part of the file name -->
  <div><strong>Download:</strong> <a href="{{ field.url }}" target="new">{{ file_name }}</a></div>
{% endfor %}
```